# Disable Active Storage in Rails 5.2

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Upgrading Rails to 5.2, and I found out that I must commit the storage.yml into version control. I don't plan to use ActiveStorage. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Remove next line from `config/application.rb`

```
require "active_storage/engine"
```

Remove next line from environments `config/environments/*.rb`

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Remove next line from `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require activestorage
```

ActiveStorage rails routes will vanish

In case there is statement `require 'rails/all'` in `application.rb` then you can use solution provided below where you need to require dependency by dependency and to omit `active_storage`.

Comment: I've done this but running rake routes still yields the `/rails/active_storage...` routes

Comment: Now it's little bit different because in `application.rb` there is statement `require 'rails/all'` so you need to require dependency by dependency and make sure not to omit something important. See answer below for reference.

Comment: I've just tested it, below solution works for this case when there is `require 'rails/all'`

Answer (score 27):

The only solution I've found so far is in `config/application.rb`, replacing:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

With:

```
require "rails"

# Include each railties manually, excluding `active_storage/engine`
%w(
  active_record/railtie
  action_controller/railtie
  action_view/railtie
  action_mailer/railtie
  active_job/railtie
  action_cable/engine
  rails/test_unit/railtie
  sprockets/railtie
).each do |railtie|
  begin
    require railtie
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

which is taken from Rails' [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2e7e9fe1dc01c782a806f62365b69584c3cb7375/railties/lib/rails/all.rb#L3).

Comment: After applying this, I get the following error when running `rails routes`:

`NoMethodError: undefined method "active_storage" for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x00005589ab85b968>`

Comment: You probably have an `active_storage ` reference in your `config/application.rb` file ;)

Answer (score 3):

Remove lines like the following from `config/environments/*.rb`

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Rails will then not load the yaml file.

Comment: Will this completely stop the engine to be loaded at app boot? Isn't there something like `config.active_storage = false` ?

Comment: @codingaddicted I didn't see that in the document. Well my main issue is that it tries to load a YAML file which I don't want/need.

Comment: yes the docs aren't quite complete I believe. Lot's of my questions stay without response about active storage for now :(

Comment: @codingaddicted if your solution works? Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I didn't find a solution yet, I think @MikeRogers0 approach can worth a try. I don't understand why you got a negative rating on yours as it is a valid alternative too. up for the balance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this migrating from Rails 5 to 6. I'm also not using active storage, had removed all references to it, and had tried the answer above overriding the `require rails/all` idea, yet still ran into this error.

It was actually simpler to commit an empty `config/storage.yml` into source. This doesn't mean you need to start using ActiveStorage anywhere in your app (to OP's original point), and will give you a more standard rails configuration, rather than worry about diverging from what `require rails/all` does in future updates.

For completeness, here's the boilerplate `config/storage.yml` you can add to address this issue.

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
# amazon:
#   service: S3
#   access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
#   secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
#   region: us-east-1
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Remember not to checkin your GCS keyfile to a repository
# google:
#   service: GCS
#   project: your_project
#   credentials: <%= Rails.root.join("path/to/gcs.keyfile") %>
#   bucket: your_own_bucket

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the Azure Storage secret (as azure_storage:storage_access_key)
# microsoft:
#   service: AzureStorage
#   storage_account_name: your_account_name
#   storage_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:azure_storage, :storage_access_key) %>
#   container: your_container_name

# mirror:
#   service: Mirror
#   primary: local
#   mirrors: [ amazon, google, microsoft ]
```