# Active Storage causing Rails app to fail on Heroku; works locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app that works fine locally.  It does not require any database.  I am trying to deploy it using Heroku, but this is the only information I am getting in my logs as to why it's not working:

```
2018-09-14T17:27:28.074554+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=4da3eec1-23dd-4d1a-ae8f-7b05086d20fc fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-14T17:27:28.469113+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=f079f20e-a9c1-4547-b563-3c2822b89e2d fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My log level is set to DEBUG.  No idea where else to look or how to tackle this problem.

EDIT:

I went back in the logs and I found this:

```
2018-09-14T17:37:19.872142+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has_one_attached' for #<Class:0x00000007a055f8> (NoMethodError)
```

I had not heard of ActiveStorage before now, but it's not something I'm using (at least not intentionally).

Log dump:

`` 2018-09-14T17:46:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user username@gmail.com
2018-09-14T17:46:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-09-14T17:47:09.445004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=6dca7f6f-3afd-4bcd-b144-f63b85994472 fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-14T17:47:09.792706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=1818345c-2dfb-4a30-ada6-65ca3bbc04ea fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-14T17:56:48.278447+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user username@gmail.com
2018-09-14T17:56:52.733021+00:00 heroku[run.7080]: Awaiting client
2018-09-14T17:56:52.763164+00:00 heroku[run.7080]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2018-09-14T17:56:52.907308+00:00 heroku[run.7080]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-14T17:57:00.092474+00:00 heroku[run.7080]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-14T17:57:00.107737+00:00 heroku[run.7080]: State changed from up to complete
2018-09-14T17:58:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user username@gmail.com
2018-09-14T17:58:40.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-09-14T17:59:08.348804+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user username@gmail.com
2018-09-14T17:59:14.334567+00:00 heroku[run.7746]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-14T17:59:14.252562+00:00 heroku[run.7746]: Awaiting client
2018-09-14T17:59:14.278462+00:00 heroku[run.7746]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2018-09-14T17:59:22.174620+00:00 heroku[run.7746]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-14T17:59:22.189708+00:00 heroku[run.7746]: State changed from up to complete
2018-09-14T17:59:56.283122+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by user username@gmail.com
2018-09-14T18:00:05.530380+00:00 heroku[run.7894]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-14T18:00:05.579669+00:00 heroku[run.7894]: Awaiting client
2018-09-14T18:00:05.633999+00:00 heroku[run.7894]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2018-09-14T18:00:20.779574+00:00 heroku[run.7894]: State changed from up to complete
2018-09-14T18:00:20.763154+00:00 heroku[run.7894]: Process exited with status 1
2018-09-14T18:01:58.718055+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=989475e7-affc-41a2-ade6-5cf21ce746a9 fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-09-14T18:01:59.041312+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=calendarizer.herokuapp.com request_id=38c77377-2758-4a31-9219-6dcb548a5b1e fwd="65.207.79.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https ``

Comment: Can you run `heroku logs --tail` and then view the app on Heroku and see if that gives you some usable information.

Comment: @RockwellRice That's what I did to get the original unhelpful message, but I dug back a little further and found the update above

Comment: Also, the log says that I should check my build logs, but I can't find any logs other than the one I'm tailing.

Comment: @RockwellRice No models, no database, no migrations in this app.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace you get when trying to view the page with `heroku logs --tail` running, these 3 lines is just not showing everything.

Comment: @RockwellRice Done

Answer (score 0):

Heroku usually wants to see some kind of database (ie pg) to run if something is going to get saved, which I believe having ActiveRecord in your app is going to imply (even if you don't intend to use it).   So you have two solutions I believe.  In your dev & test environment you likely have sqlite3 as your database (you can look in your gemfile), but Heroku doesn't work with sqlite3.

Option 1:
   Disable ActiveRecord in your app - Following this post: [Disable Active Storage in Rails 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813214/disable-active-storage-in-rails-5-2)

Option 2:
   Add a database to your production environment for heroku, so it's happy:
   - in your gemfile see if you have a production group already

```
group :production do
```

- if not add it
- add in the pg gem:

  gem 'pg'

So you should end up with something like this in your gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then commit and push to Heroku.  You may need to restart the Dynos in Heroku, and you may need to create the database files on heroku too:

```
heroku run rails db:create
```

You should be up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the adapter in `database.yml` was `sqlite3`.
So I changed the production section of `config/database.yml` to:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicodeubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  database: myapp_production
  username: myapp
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```